# Troubles linking to FB Page via status update

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

**[UPDATE]  [I checked this StackExchange out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24244/how-do-you-link-to-a-facebook-page-in-a-comment-using-its-pageid), but this does not work! It converts the typed in markup language into this question mark...**

[image: Facebook Question Mark]

---

I manage a Facebook Page that deals with music videos, and I always **link back** to the original artist / group for **discovery purposes (the reason for this question)** and giving credit to them. However, I am having a difficult time with one link to a specific group.

The main Facebook Page title that I am trying to link to is [**15&**](https://www.facebook.com/15andOfficial)

*Normally, in a post, you would type in `@15&` or `@Stack Overflow`, and you would select the correct item from the drop-down menu. As such...*

---

[image: Facebook Link via Status Update]

---

**However, that does not work because of the `&` at the end of the name. That stops me from linking to that page. There are no more suggestions in the drop-down to choose from.**

However, I thought there was a workaround to this by linking through the ID, but I have not been able to figure it out.

Something like, `@[PageID]`. In my case, `@[413447808702858]`; **however, this does not work!?**

**What is the workaround to doing this?**

Here is the [Facebook Graph for 15&](http://graph.facebook.com/413447808702858), but I copy-pasted the text below.

```
{
   "id": "413447808702858",
   "about": "15& Official Facebook",
   "band_members": "\ubc15\uc9c0\ubbfc (Jimin)\n\ubc31\uc608\ub9b0 (Yerin)",
   "can_post": false,
   "category": "Musician/band",
   "checkins": 0,
   "cover": {
      "cover_id": 677497282297908,
      "offset_x": 0,
      "offset_y": 0,
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t1.0-9/s720x720/10320593_677497282297908_5814182992929119023_n.jpg"
   },
   "has_added_app": false,
   "is_community_page": false,
   "is_published": true,
   "likes": 151126,
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/15andOfficial",
   "name": "15&",
   "parking": {
      "lot": 0,
      "street": 0,
      "valet": 0
   },
   "record_label": "JYP Entertainment",
   "talking_about_count": 5017,
   "username": "15andOfficial",
   "website": "http://15and.jype.com, http://cafe.daum.net/15And,     http://twitter.com/jypnation, http://www.youtube.com/jypentertainment",
   "were_here_count": 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type the page's username, this will give the exact page name with that `username`

[image: 15&]

the page username is `15andOfficial`

Comment: Thank you. I swear I tried that earlier and it was not working. That is why I dug up the facebook graph. Anyways, thanks.